# Should Rails render :unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing an form. After user submits the form data to rails, rails will authentication first and then response.
I cannot remember exactly. But previously, I read an article, whose key point is rails shall never return Client Error status in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html to front end. Instead, if processing user data and found there is something wrong with the data, rails needs to `render json:{error:error_message}`, which is successful response from server. And then front end will extract the `error` from json. But my another team member said, if checking the data is wrong, we shall return client wrong status(such as `400`, `401`) to front end directly. Which method is right?

Answer (score 0):

I think either of the two is correct.

Rails will automatically generate a response with the correct **HTTP** status code and mostly readable by end-user.

But if you really want to catch the **status** for frontend viewing.

You can use the **:status option** to change this:

```
render status: 500
render status: :forbidden
```